# angular tree control not highlighting the whole cell

Tags: angularjs, css

I tried to implement angular tree control from http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control, however, i cannot highlight the whole cell, it's only highlighting the label.  I tried to change the css that the treecontrol comes with but still i can't make it highlight the whole cell.

the current and expected result is here:

[image]

```
treecontrol {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
treecontrol ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
treecontrol li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    ul {
      padding-left: 16px;
    }
    .tree-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline;
      &:focus {
        outline: none;
      }
      &:hover {
        outline: none;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    }
    .tree-selected {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    &.tree-expanded {
      > div {
        > .tree-icon-expand {
          display: none;
        }
        > .tree-icon-collapse {
          display: inline;
        }
      }
    }
 }

treecontrol li.tree-expanded i.tree-leaf-head, treecontrol li.tree-collapsed i.tree-leaf-head {display:none;}
treecontrol li.tree-expanded i.tree-branch-head, treecontrol li.tree-collapsed i.tree-branch-head {display:inline;}
treecontrol li.tree-leaf i.tree-branch-head {display:none;}
treecontrol li.tree-leaf i.tree-leaf-head {display:inline;}

treecontrol li i.tree-branch-head {
  cursor: pointer;
}

treecontrol li.tree-expanded i.tree-branch-head {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background: url("../images/node-opened-light.png") no-repeat;
}

treecontrol li.tree-collapsed i.tree-branch-head {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background: url("../images/node-closed-light.png") no-repeat;
}

treecontrol li.tree-leaf i.tree-leaf-head {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  width: 16px; height: 16px;
  background: none no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to see some HTML that the CSS relates to

Comment: Sir, as mentioned in the above, I just implement the angular tree control. In the link, the html is just  <treecontrol tree-model="treedata" on-selection="showSelected(node)">
     {{node.label}}
 </treecontrol>

Comment: able to create a fiddle  ?

Comment: the entire area you're trying to highlight does not belong to `ul` element. In any case, the color seems to be applying on the label instead of the list item. Try accessing `li` and changing its color

Answer (score 4):

You have an example in the same page that you linked

[custom css classes](http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/#custom-css)

Your javascript would be

```
 function CustomCss($scope) {
     $scope.treedata=createSubTree(3, 4, "");
     $scope.opts = {
         injectClasses: {
             "liSelected": "c-liSelected",
         }
     };
 }
```

And your CSS

```
.c-liSelected {background-color: yellow}
```

Comment: when you expand it, it will still show background color on the left side that will stretch depending on how many children the node has. I was thinking of how to keep the background on the node itself only.